# How Can I Stop the Enterprise Library Configuration Tool from Inserting an Absolute Path in the Environment Configuration File field?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, enterprise-library-5

I'm trying to learn/use the Enterprise Library 5.0 Configuration tool and it seems like it would work perfectly with a few minor exceptions.  The problem I am currently having is when it comes to working with different environments.  We have 3 environments for one of our web sites, so I can create the 3 different environments within the configuration tool and I can set up the delta files and which properties to overwrite and when.

[image: Initial setup of Enterprise Library Configuration Environments]

All is well until I  **Export Merged Environment Configuration File**.  When I do this, it creates the file as intended, however it changes the *Environment Configuration File* field to now include the absolute path.

[image]

Also, the delta file now contains a reference to the absolute path.

[image]

We use source control (VSTS) - so absolute paths are no good.  Our build process consists of creating branches and then merging the code back into a root.  We can't have absolute paths when the branches are created by different team members having their code in a different local folder structure.

Is there any way to stop the absolute path from automatically being added?  Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research indicates that there does not seem to be a way to make the GUI tool not override the Environment Configuration File value.  The solution I am going with is to use the command line tool provided when installing the Enterprise Library.  The command line tool is MergeConfiguration.exe.